# WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlowDNNRegressor class is deprecated. Please consider using DNNRegressor as an alternative

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

Yesterday, I had updated Tensorflow to version 0.9 from 0.8. After which, I am observing the following warning with my Skflow models. Could anyone please let me know what this means? Is there a way to fix it? Are there alternate methods to model DNN Regressor with Skflow?

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1197:
> VisibleDeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an
> index will result in an error in the future result_shape.insert(dim,
> 1)
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlowDNNRegressor class is deprecated.
> Please consider using DNNRegressor as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a Warning so your model will train fine. Skflow (or TFLearn same thing) advises you to use `skflow.DNNRegressor` instead of `skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor`.

Here are the arguments of `DNNRegressor` and the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#DNNClassifier):

```
tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier.__init__(
  hidden_units,
  feature_columns=None,
  model_dir=None,
  n_classes=2,
  weight_column_name=None,
  optimizer=None,
  activation_fn=relu,
  dropout=None,
  config=None)
```

However, according to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712723/tensorflowdnnclassifier-class-is-deprecated-but-replacement-does-not-seem-to-wor), the new function does not work yet so I will advise you to stay with the old one for now !

Comment: @OliverMoindrot: Thanks for your reply and advise!

Comment: @OliverMoindrot: Just a small question, Are these changes mainly redefining the names of the classes? Or are there improvements to the wrapper as well? Then, will the hyperparameters defined within my old models hold well? Do I need to tune the model again?

Comment: I don't know much about skflow/tflearn, and the documentation is not very clear. But I believe this is not just renaming, the new function will be better. However, if you keep the same hyperparameters you should see the the same results.

Comment: Maybe my [recent blog](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/) would help you understand the changes better.