# Is DNNClassifier unstable compared with TensorFlowDNNClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, skflow

I'm building a DNN predicted (0 or 1) model based on skflow with TF v0.9.
My code with `TensorFlowDNNClassifier` is like this. I train about 26,000 records and test 6,500 one.

```
classifier = learn.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[64, 128, 64], n_classes=2)
classifier.fit(features, labels, steps=50000)
test_pred = classifier.predict(test_features)
print(classification_report(test_labels, test_pred))
```

It takes about 1 minute and gets a result.

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support
          0       0.77      0.92      0.84      4265
          1       0.75      0.47      0.58      2231
avg / total       0.76      0.76      0.75      6496
```

But I got

```
WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlowDNNClassifier class is deprecated. 
Please consider using DNNClassifier as an alternative.
```

So I updated my code with `DNNClassifier` simply.

```
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[64, 128, 64], n_classes=2)
classifier.fit(features, labels, steps=50000)
```

It also works well. But result was not the same.

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support
          0       0.77      0.96      0.86      4265
          1       0.86      0.45      0.59      2231
avg / total       0.80      0.79      0.76      6496
```

**`1` 's precision is improved**. 
Of course this is a good for me, but why it is improved? 
And It takes about 2 hours. 
**This is about 120 times slower** than previous example.

Do I have something wrong? or miss some parameters? 
Or is `DNNClassifier` unstable with TF v0.9?

Answer (score 0):

I give the same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208156/828184). You might experience that because you used the steps parameter instead of **max_steps**. It was just steps on TensorFlowDNNClassifier that in reality did max_steps. Now you can decide if you really want that in your case 50000 steps or auto abort earlier.